# invocation of hibernate session.get method

Tags: java, hibernate

I am aware of all these terminology like new, transient, detached etc. However, sometimes I am stuck with the questions like --

what actually happens when you invoke hibernate session.get method invoked? 
 - hibernate will create the instance with empty constructor ??
 - will invoked the setters ?

Can you please shed your thoughts on this.

Comment: Have you tried to put breakpoints in your entity class to see some of it's behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> what actually happens when you invoke hibernate session.get method invoked? - hibernate will create the instance with empty constructor ?? - will invoked the setters ?

YES. Hibernate will invoke the `no-argument constructor` to create the beans after fetching the data. The it will call the setter methods to set the corresponding values. That why hibernate gives error when any of the getters/setters is missing.

As mentioned in the comments you can set the debug points and see this happening.

Comment: I disagree . If a property is configured to be access by field , it is okay if we do not define the setter for that property.

Answer (score 0):

> what actually happens when you invoke hibernate session.get method
>   invoked? - hibernate will create the instance with empty constructor
>   ?? - will invoked the setters ?

It depends on whether the current session has already managed an instance with the same PK and whether the properties of the mapped entity is configured to be the access by property or access by field.

If the current session has already managed an instance with the same PK , that instance will be returned . No new instance will be created in this case .

Otherwise , a new instance will be created by calling the empty constructor first . Then setters  will be invoked for those properties that are configured to be  access by properties. For those  properties that are configured to be  access by fields , their setter will not be invoked as hibernate will directly inject the values to those fields.

See [this](http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com/2010/04/field-versus-property-access-in.html) for more information about the field access and property access .